# Compulsory option of jQuery plugin

Tags: c#, php, asp.net, jquery

I am making my custom jQuery plugin whose code is this:

```
(function($) {

    $.fn.foo = function(options) {
        var opt = $.extend({}, $.fn.foo.defaults, options);

        return this.each(function() {
            //do operation with opt
        });

    });


    $.foo.defaults = {
        item1:'value1',
            item2:'value2',
            item3:'value3',
        };

})(jQuery);
```

It will be implemented like this:

```
 //Implementation
 $(...).foo({
      item1:'value1',
      item2:'value2',
      item3:'value3',
      item4:'value4',
 });
```

My question is that how can I make *item4* value to be compulsory? I want that user must enter value for *Item4* . In my plugin I need to do some operations with item4 so how can it be made compulsory. I will be having one or more items too which should be compulsory. Is there any way by which I can warn user if the that value is not passed by the user ?

Comment: You can't. You can only throw an error when the user doesn't supply `item4`

Comment: By user you mean developer right? Why not just use default values? http://jquery-howto.blogspot.com/2009/01/how-to-set-default-settings-in-your.html

Comment: I am looking for a way so that user can know that he has to enter that item too

Comment: I can't set it default too I think, say the item4 is the value of server control. So it is must, that it should be passed from outside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (!options.item4) {
    alert('Give me an item 4!');
    console.log('Item 4!');
    return false;
}
```

Comment: thanks I appreciate that!, is there any way (XML commenting etc) I want the developer to know with intellisense too so that he can know that is must.

Comment: @Rocky Not that I know of (not that I'm using VS either). You're trying to require a certain *structure of* an argument, not an argument itself. I wouldn't know of any way to mark that up in code or comment. If JS did type hinting, you could require an object of a certain type, but JS doesn't even do that...